Modulation Bandwidth of LED
Following on my previous post I have photodiode connected to OpAmp in inverting transimpedance configuration. (Circuit diagram can be found in previous post).
Excitation source is 4000K LED with unknown bandwidth. datasheet
Photodiode in operation is BPX61 datasheet.
OpAmp in operation is LTC6228 Datasheet
I'm trying to measure modulation bandwidth of LED. I know that 3 dB point is where the voltage gets half of its initial which I'm measuring at 10 kHz. Although voltage level is not decreasing as I increase the frequency of LED, the signal shape changes significantly.
Where should I take as 3 dB point? Or any other suggestion to measure it better?




Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The issue is probably how you're driving the LED.  They're nonlinear circuit elements, so if you try to drive them as you would a resistor by modulating voltage they don't respond linearly.  Instead, you typically modulate current:

(taken from this presentation: https://www.slideserve.com/kalyca/light-sources-ii-the-laser-and-external-modulation)
Since current approaches zero a little below the forward voltage (~3V in this case), you end up with a drive voltage waveform that goes between 3V and a few hundred millivolts higher than that.
If you drive it the way you're doing, what is happening is that at lower frequency, you spend a lot of time charging and discharging the diode capacitance at voltages where it isn't emitting.  As the frequency increases, you start to get a more sinusoidal output because there is no longer enough time to discharge the diode capacitance, but probably also you're getting a lower amplitude.
Since it sounds like you do not want to build a current driver, I would try adjusting your drive waveform to go between 3.0 and 3.3V and then steadily lowering any series resistance.  As you increase the frequency, try also increasing the voltage swing.  At very high frequencies you can use a 50 ohm (or lower) source and swing up to 4V or more without having too much current flow.  If you play with it, you can get up to MHz frequencies with even through hole diodes.

Beyond a MHz or so you'll probably want to look for a more suitable LED.  A small area SMD diode will work better than through hole, and above a few MHz the 10s of nanosecond fluorescent lifetime of the phosphor on your diode will start to become apparent, and you'll see it start to limit your bandwidth.

thank you. I'll try to use a laser current driver and see the impact. One thing I should have underlined that I was not using single LED but couple of LEDs in series. I'll try single LED with offset voltage as well as with current driver and get back to you.
